How do I split a file path using XSL 1.0
Our test executive uses stylesheets to generate test reports. We are working to customize the report.
With limited knowledge of XSL and Xpath, I am trying to get individual components of a file path and present them in the report. We are limited to XSL 1.0.
<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

returns a file path like:
C:\blahblahblah\part\rev\testname.seq

C:\blah... is of variable length.
The remaining path structure will always be ..\part\rev\testname.seq
What I want is:
TestName: <testname>   Part:<part>   Rev: <rev>   

I have tried various nesting of substring-before / substring-after, however, the portion of the file path before the relevant portions can be of various size.
The best I have been able to do is remove the file extension as I am not very knowledgeable in this area.

It's not clear what in your example is constant and what is just an example. Will there always be exactly three backslashes before the filename? Is the testname  really surrounded by angle brackets? You need to state clearly what can be used by the extraction process to parse the given string.

@michael.hor257k My apologies, The first portion of the path C:\blah... is of variable length. The remaining path structure will always be..\part\rev\testname.seq

That doesn't answer my questions. If the number of backslashes is not known, then you'll need to use a method similar to the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41625340/3016153. Unless your processor happens to support tokenizing as an extension function.

Since I will always have \part\rev\testname.seq, then yes, there will always be those three slashes, though more could precede this portion of the path. Unfortunately, I am limited to XSL 1.0.

If you don't know the exact number of slashes in the entire string, then you will need to iterate until only 3 (and 2 and 1) remain. Unless ... Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? Some do support extension functions, which could save a lot of work here.

@michael.hor257k Unfortunately, I am very new at the whole XSLT thing. I am using NI Teststand, which is a test executive if you are unfamiliar with it, that will generate an HTML report based on supplied stylesheets. As best as I can tell from system-property, the version is 1.

Please get the vendor property too - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

The results of both vendor and version are "Microsoft" and "1" respectively.

That's too bad.

Consider the following example:
XML
<input name="C:\blah\blaah\blaaah\part\rev\testname.seq"/>

XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <results>
        <xsl:call-template name="parse-path">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="parse-path">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <!-- count delimiters -->
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="string-length(translate($text, translate($text, '\', ''), ''))"/>
    <!-- extract data -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$n=2">
            <part>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '\')"/>
            </part>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$n=1">
            <rev>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '\')"/>
            </rev>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$n=0">
            <testname>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '.')"/>
            </testname>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:if test="$n">
        <xsl:call-template name="parse-path">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '\')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <part>part</part>
   <rev>rev</rev>
   <testname>testname</testname>
</results>


While I think I'm starting to understand how this should work, I'm having an issue with this since I'm not exactly sure what the first <xsl:template match.. should match. In this example, I get that I am looking for Item and the attribute is my path, but since the XML is internally generated by the Teststand Engine, I'm not sure what element I should be looking for to match with. Is there a way to tell?

It should match the element that has the name attribute. IOW, the named template should be called from the same context where your current <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> instruction is. I cannot be more specific without seeing your input XML (which you should be able to see by applying a stylesheet with only the identity transform template).

I am adding the named template after a test, <xsl:when test="contains(@name)">. If I need to explicitly match the element that has the name attribute, I'm not sure how to find out which element that is. My concern is that <xsl:template match="input"/> won't work because no node named "input" exists. I tried matching on the attribute, but that didn't work either.

The named template needs to stand on its own (like any other template). Please read again what I wrote about where to place the call to the named template. --- P.S. XSLT is not intuitive, you won't be able to make it work by trial-and-error. You need to have a basic understanding before you can ask questions here. <xsl:when test="contains(@name)"> makes no sense and will produce an error.

Thank you for all of your help, Michael. I've certainly been learning a lot and I really appreciate your time.

I figured out what I was missing, and it looks like this might work out for me! Thank's for putting up with someone with about 20 hours of XLS knowledge. You certainly made my day!
